# Ayuda cargar ComboBox JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

bueno tengo un problema y es que quiero cargar un `ComboBox` con datos devueltos por una base de datos y hasta acá todo bien. La cosa es que al ejecutar el método el cual llenaría el `ComboBox` lanza error de compilación.

Este es el error: **java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

```
public class FXMLDocumentRegisterController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXComboBox<String> CmbCountry;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        loadCmb();//aca ejecuto el metodo de carga del combobox
    }

    private void loadCmb(){//este metodo carga el combobox con los datos devueltos de la base de datos
        RepoPais repo = FabricaReposSQL.CrearRepoPais();
        Iterable<Pais> p = repo.FindAll();  for (Pais pais : p) {
            CmbCountry.getItems().add(pais.Nombre);     
        }
    }
}
```

El error se produce en la linea en la cual se agrega el Item al ComboBox: `CmbCountry.getItems().add(pais.Nombre);`

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias :)

Comment: Esa excepción en principió no tendría motivo por el que lanzarse en esa línea de código a no ser que haya un error en acceder a pais.Nombre en tiempo de ejecución. Relacionado con el ComboBox, en principio es así tal como lo tienes. Yo haría una prueba rápida de crear un getter de nombre público (No es muy buena praxis lo de tener fields accesibles. Aunque no tenga que ver con la pregunta, los nombres de fields de una clase, según las Java Conventions, deben empezar en minúsculas).

Answer (score -1):

una posible solución podría ser esta. En primer lugar, debes cargar los paises en un ObservableList. Algo así:

```
private ObservableList<String> paises = FXCollection.observableArrayList();
```

Añades los países que quieras al observable:

```
paises.add("España");
paises.add("Francia");
```

Y una vez que tengas el observable cargado con los países te puedes hacer un método genérico que carge cualquier combobox con cualquier observable. Algo así:

```
public static void loadCombo(ComboBox<String> combo, ObservableList<String> paises) { 

    if (null != combo) {
       combo.setItems(paises);
    } 
}
```

Una vez creado esto, sólo tenemos que usarlo:

```
Util.loadCombo(comboBoxPaises,paises);
```

Espero que os sirva, y disculpar no haber podido responder adecuadamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta podría ser correcta, se considera de baja calidad ya que, además del código, deberías explicar como esto soluciona el problema del OP. Te recomiendo pasarte por [answer], asi como hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primer medalla.Saludos!

Comment: Disculpar haber contestado a la ligera. He corregido y he dado una posible solución. Saludos!